# Background-image(url) casuing double post back asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

My page is double posting back and figured out where it was but not sure how to fix.  If I delete this line:

```
<div class="item-image" style="background-image:url('<%#Eval("DEFIMAGE") %>');"><a href="itemDetail.aspx?id=<%#Eval("PROID") %>">
```

Or just they style part with the background-image it doesn't do it anymore.  However I need that as it shows my image in my grid.

Any fixes for this did research and most places say that the double is caused by a blank src or url but mine is filled.

Comment: What's the generated source?

Comment: @SLaks you mean what is the src of the "DEFIMAGE" it's pulling?

Comment: No; I mean the HTML source it generates in your page.

Comment: @SLaks I posted it above... its just  a div inside an ASP repeater.  But here is what it looks like after it loads style="background-image:url('proImages/100048-3.jpg');"

Comment: No, you didn't post the generated HTML. You posted the original ASPX markup. The actual HTML will be generated based on that and sent to the client's browser.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and it seems to be working great now

```
<div class="item-image"><img src="<%#Eval("DEFIMAGE") %>" width="100%" /><a href="itemDetail.aspx?id=<%# Eval("PROID") %>">
```